# Cannot resolve symbol (any ID's) Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm a noob Android studio programmer (this is hour 2 of learning!) and I expect this is a real rookie error I'm making!

I've got a *Plain Text* field in my application and I would like to set the text of this dynamically. I've given the plain text field the ID of: "resultText". Here's what I try;

```
    public void calcnums(View v)
{
    int x=firstNum + seondNum;
    resultText.setText("Result: " + x);
}
```

For some reason I get 'resultText' highlighted in red and the hover over message is; Cannot resolve symbol 'resultText'.

I have the feeling that I'm doing something wrong by using the ID, but I'm lost!

Full code as suggested in comments;

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class AddNumbers extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int firstNum;
    private int seondNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_numbers);
    }

    public void calcnums(View v)
    {
        int x=firstNum + seondNum;
        resultText.setText(String.format("Result: %d", x);
    }
    public void setNums(View v)
    {
        TextView tx= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Random r = new Random();
        int x=r.nextInt(2) + 1;  // r.nextInt(2) returns either 0 or 1
        firstNum = x;
        r = new Random();
        x=r.nextInt(2) + 1;
        seondNum = x;
        num1.setText(""+firstNum);
        num2.setText(""+seondNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: If whoever downvoted could let me know how to improve the question I would appreciate it.

Comment: Post your complete layout and activity code so someone might help.

Comment: @Drv thank, I've added all the code now! The error occurs on 'resultText', 'num1' and 'num2'.

Comment: where is the variable for resultText?

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg Please upload your activity_add_numbers.xml file too.

Comment: you have not  declared `resultText` Field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to declare the View resultText

Like,

```
EditText resultText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
```

Also make sure that the name you are using for the **resultText** View in xml is written correctly as provided in the method **findViewById()**

usually **cannot resolve symbol** means some problems in variable declarations.

I am too learning android and I stumbled upon this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the whole snippet of your code.But the thing you might be missing is to point your EditText object to view in xml.

EditText resultText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.result_edit_text);

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/result_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/result_edit_text"
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that we have an layout with an edittext

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@id/txt_user_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />
```

It has an ID. In your actitivy you must find and cast the EditText as follow:

```
EditText txtUserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_user_email);
txtUserEmail.setText("klaus.dieter@lusty-swingers.de");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to find your text view in `onCreate()`, like that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_numbers);
    TextView tx= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
}
```